# Pass id from public function to other public function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got a public function call header:

```
public function header() {
    $link = Link::with('page', 'tag')->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')->first();
    $link_id = $link->id;

    return view('site.templates.linksheader', compact('link'));
}
```

And I got a public function call index2:

```
public function index2() {

    $links = Link::where('status', '=', 1)
            ->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
            ->with('page', 'tag')
            //->whereNotIn('id', $id);
            ->take(12)
            ->get();
}
```

In the `->whereNotIn` of `index2`, I want to get the `$id` of function `header()`...

Comment: `$this->link_id = $link->id` then use `whereNotIn('id', $this->link_id)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
public function header() {
    $link = $this->getFirstLink();

    return view('site.templates.linksheader', compact('link'));
}
```

And

```
public function index2() {

    $links = Link::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
        ->with('page', 'tag')
        ->whereNotIn('id', $this->getFirstLink()->id);
        ->take(12)
        ->get();
}
```

And

```
private function getFirstLink() {
    return Link::with('page', 'tag')->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')->first();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. return $link->id should be returning an integer if you have your models configured properly

Comment: Great! Mark the answer to close the question.